# How to get selected data from combobox and upload it to mysql database?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to get selected data from combobox and upload it to mysql database, but it's not working as expected. Here is my code:

```
        Try
        Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand
        Dim insertStatment As String = "INSERT INTO comment (name,comment,reason)  
         VALUES (@name,@comment, @reason)"
        cmd2 = New MySqlCommand(insertStatment, db_con)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", richtxtcomment.Text)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("reason", combobox.SelectedValue)

        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Thank your for your comment")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("bad")
        db_con.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

Comment: Did you miss the @ infront of the reason parameter? or is just a typo?

Comment: Please change that catch block to show the effective message, (if any) try with MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) and tell us what do you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the items in your ComboBox were added, there are different properties to use:

- `SelectedIndex` gets the index of the selected item.
- `SelectedItem` gets the object that's selected.
- `SelectedText` gets the text that's selected.
- `SelectedValue` gets the ValueMember property of the selected item.

So if you didn't set the [ValueMember property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx), then it's going to be null.  If you want to store what's displayed in the combo box, use SelectedText:

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reason", combobox.SelectedText)
```

If you want to store some property or the result of a method of the object in the ComboBox use SelectedItem:

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reason", combobox.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

Comment: its just text, it has 3 differ things for the user to choose from.

Comment: it just uploads a blank to the db, i change "selectvalue" to "selectext" and insted of a null value i have a blank value in my db

Comment: Try SelectedItem.ToString()